# Switching to empty hand with more than 2 items equipped

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls 2 you're able to switch to an empty hand, if you only have 1 item equipped.

For example:

Main-hand:

- sword
- Empty
- Empty

Off-hand:

- Shield
- Empty
- Empty

But, because I want to use a brawler build, I'd like to change into my empty hands (fists) because of the Vanquiser's ring.

The **desired** build I want to use is:

Main-hand:

- Bone fist
- Empty
- Empty

Off-Hand

- Bone fist
- Pyromancy flame
- Empty

Is it possible to use the desired build and be able to switch back to empty hands (fists)?
Or can the pyromancy flame be considered a "fist"?

Comment: Have you attempted this yourself? In Dark Souls 1, Pyromancy Flame is **not** considered a *fist*, so I'm assuming it's the very same in Dark Souls 2.

Comment: @FinnRayment No, I haven't attempted it myself. It is true that it is the same as in DS1, but in DS2 the powerstance mechanic was introduced: so it may be changed. I will test that this evening, I'll update my question if I know more.

Comment: Ok. It's always good to try yourself before asking, unless it involves going to alot of trouble or loosing something valuable if it fails (like buying a useless item for Souls).

Comment: I want to try it myself, but I have yet to find a Bone fist.. Otherwise I would've tested it myself. You can always wear a life-protection ring the prevent losses of valuables.

Comment: Ok. I just didn't know. Good luck! (sorry I can't help, only got DS1)

Answer (score 1):

No. The Pyromancy Flame is considered a Catalyst, like a Staff or Chime. While they can be used as weapons, their main weapon class is a Catalyst.

So, basically, no; you cannot use the pyromancy flame as a "fist weapon" or as an "empty fist", and therefore cannot be dual wielded.

**Edit:** I should add that even though there are three slots for you to use, only two are used *unless* the third slot is occupied. For example, if at least 1 of the three slots is left empty, only the first two slots can be selected or "equipped".

So if you want to use the Vanquisher's Seal, you will need to have at least two empty slots on each hand to "dual wield" your fists.